# giving a different value to a variable on each different value from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JS array with more than a million entries.

I want JavaScript to assign a specific color to flag on every different value from the array

say that my Array contains this:

```
var foo = new Array([10,20,30,40,50,36,60,70,80,90,100]);
```

It is worth knowing that my array contains 58 different values.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
if (foo.every(10)) flag = "red";
if (foo.every(20)) flag =  "yellow";
```

I need a way to do it for all the values in the array without having to repeat the line above 58 times.

note that I know that the flag will be overridden and the flag in my code is unique for every different value.

Also note that the array is imported as JSON data from a MySQL table using PHP, so any PHP approaches to this problem will also be appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for is mapping the values to a unique color then you will have to create an object that a key/value association between all your different possible values and their respective associated color.

Comment: You need to specify what the color types should be + you need to get all the unique values from the array. If you down want to repeat the assigning 58 you must generate the colors differently. Maybe random colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy JS solution:

```
var numberToColorDictionary = {
    10: "red",
    20: "yellow"
    ...
}

// After this runs, 'flags' should contain all the right flags. 
var flags = foo.map(function(number) {
    return numberToColorDictionary[number];
});
```

Although, this does sound like you're querying your database wrong. If the numbers are ids from MySQL, you should use `join` to get the correct flags.

And by the way, you don't need the `new Array` syntax. just do:

```
var foo = [10,20,30,40,50,36,60,70,80,90,100];
```

Comment: this looks like the right thing to try. and no the values i get from the database are not the ids not even  numbers. we will be back in a minute with an update